# How can get Hard Disk Information Using CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, command, admin, hard-drive

I am use this command for finding hard disk in formation "wmic diskdrive" but i insert a external device like hard disk or pan drive, this command is provide information of external hard disk or pan drive. so how can find internal hard disk information where system window installed.

Answer (score 12):

It is off topic here , though you can get the info using following `cmd`

```
wmic logicaldisk
```

or ,

`diskpart` then `list volume`

Comment: i want serial number and model number of hard disk

Comment: try this `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber`

Comment: i have tried this but when i insert pan drive it provide pan drive serial number. by using these command

Comment: how can get only hard disk serial number??

Comment: `wmic diskdrive get caption,serialnumber`

Answer (score 5):

The PowerShell way is:

```
PS C:\> $Disk = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'"
PS C:\> $DiskPartition = $Disk.GetRelated('Win32_DiskPartition')
PS C:\> $DiskDrive = $DiskPartition.GetRelated('Win32_DiskDrive')
PS C:\> $DiskDrive.Size
1024203640320
```

This is nicely explained [here](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/01/26/view-drive-information-with-powershell.aspx).

But the original question was about how to do this with CMD.

```
C:\>wmic diskdrive get model,name,size
Model                       Name                Size
SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-000L7  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  1024203640320
Generic- SD/MMC USB Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
```

Given a choice, I prefer to use the PowerShell method, starting from the drive letter and working up to the physical disk.  It's rather verbose but it gives a unique answer, and requires no knowledge of the system.  (Some devices have many physical disks and it can get confusing.)

Answer (score 2):

"find internal hard disk information where system window installed."

```
wmic logicaldisk where caption="%systemdrive%" get /value
```

Note: `logicaldisk` is a partition on an physical drive (the only one, if you are lucky, but there may be more partitions on the same physical drive)